# Are there any design guidelines to Sign in with SSO (Single Sign On)?

Tags: login

Should Sign in with SSO be a button? Or should it be a link? If a button, should it be in red color, or black, or blue, etc?

Check the link "Login with SSO" in this example: https://trello.com/login

Comment: This is really something that you need to tailor to your particular situation and your users. Colour choices are mostly driven by the palette that your product carries (i.e. buttons are in your primary CTA colour) and the choice of a link or a button depends on your layout, your business goals, and many other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ronit said, the color depends upon your branding and style guide. If it is the primary way to log in, it should be a button. If it is a secondary option then it should be a link.

Comment: You should supply additional information in comments.

Answer (score 2):

For the color it depends on the palette that you are using. Personally I like the UX [sentry uses for their SSO](https://sentry.io/auth/login/) which is a more smooth experience compared to Trello's.